# MongoDB Reinitialize BulkWriteOperation after execute

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, bulkinsert

I first initialie the BulkWriteOperation and add several inserts to it through a for loop. Then I do execute. I then reinitialize the BulkWriteOperation and try to add more insert but I keep getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: already executed
```

My Code:

```
BulkWriteOperation builder = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("Something", something);
    builder.insert(doc);
}

builder.execute();

builder = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("Something", something);
    builder.insert(doc);
}

builder.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to reset the existing BulkWriteOperation object after executing it, so you just need to create a new one like this:

```
builder = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
```